# Is storing an encrypted user id in a session variable a good practice?

Tags: php, session, encryption, authentication

In this PHP script, once the user authenticates himself with his username and password, his user id is stored as an encrypted session variable to be identified throughout the web app. I was wondering if this is a good practice. If not, could you suggest some better alternatives? Can anything be done to avert session hijacking?

(I use the same method for external oauth logins too).

Below is the code snippet:

```
//------Check POST data
if(!$check_email && !$check_password && !$check_request):

    $user          = new user_auth($email);
    $authenticated = $user->user_login($password);
    $status        = $user->get_user_status();

    if($status==100 && $authenticated)
    {
        session_start();
       //-----Returns an encrypted user id
        $_SESSION['account'] = $user->get_user_id(); 
        $response = $redirect;
    }

   else
        $response = ':: Authentication failed - try again ::';
```

Comment: How is the token encrypted?  If the same user logs in twice is the result of encryption the same?

Comment: I use open SSL encrypt and de-crypt. The function $user->get_user_id() returns the encrypted user id which is assigned to a session variable. Whichever script needs to verify the user just de-crypts this session variable to get back the user id. (The user id never changes)

Comment: Do you use an IV when encrypting?

Comment: Yes of course I do use an IV. Can't do without it.

Comment: Well you can but that isn't relevant.  Do you include an expiry date or is it just the users id?  The encryption part is probably more relevant than the code you've posted.